# SSH username alias

Tags: ssh

Is possible to use username aliases with SSH? What I'm trying to do is connect to my server using `ssh site123@hostname`, and get authenticated as username `site` with an environment variable `SITEID=123`.

I can write some scripts, I just need to know where I intercept the SSH authentication process.

EDIT:

I'm trying to implement a "ssh router". One developer will `ssh projectname@host`, and he will be redirected to the right environment. I don't need to care about filesystem and UID/GID in this case, since I just will redirect the user to the right machine (with the right username).

If I `ssh project1@gateway.mycompany`, this will redirect the user to `dev@staging.project1.mycompany` (internal host!). I already do this, but I have to create a user for each project, and then setup the authorized_keys with the right command.

Comment: You should be able to accomplish this through local editing of /etc/hosts, and ~/.ssh/ssh_config. I'll come back and check, and provide a suggestion if this is still unanswered.

Comment: @mpbloch thanks for your comment. I think configuring ~/.ssh/config will be useful only in the client side, and I'm trying to achieve this without touching the client configuration.

Comment: OK, yes, then that would not work. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Offhand: no.

After some more consideration: it would depend on your environment and what you're trying to achieve.

The filesystem and much of the OS only cares about the UID/GID numbers, and you can have a many-to-one mapping there, username 'site123' can have the same UID as user 'site' and the same home directory as well.

You may want to look into pam_env too.

Comment: I've updated my question with what I need to achieve. In fact, I really don't care about permissions in this stage, since I just forward the connection to the right environment.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `command="ssh dev@staging.project1.mycompany"` at the beginning of project1@gateway.mycompany's `authorized_keys` file. If that user has the correct credentials it should let you through to the other end.

EDIT:

You can also set `SITEID=123` in that same command, if needed.

Comment: I already do this, but I have to create an user for every project, and then configure the authorized_keys for this particular user. I'm trying to centralize all the work in one place, so I can check internally if the user is allowed to access this project.

Answer (score 1):

You can send environment variables to the server, but the server must be configured to accept those:

```
server# grep SITEID /etc/ssh/sshd_config
AcceptEnv SITEID
```

Then, on the client:

```
client$ SITEID=123 ssh -o SendEnv="SITEID" user@server
server$ echo $SITEID
123
```

However, bear in mind that anybody (able to login) can set `SITEID` to anything they like.

Answer (score 1):

imo an easier less complicated way would be to just create a duplicate user eg:

Edit the below files & duplicate the site username & just modify the from part from `site` to `site123`

```
/etc/passwd
    site:x:500:500:Site User:/home/site:/bin/bash
    site123:x:500:500:Site User:/home/site:/bin/bash

/etc/shadow
    site:$6$2.ZZMqBj$kFO1qi1UqGh4y3wcSDcEM5IoCMlljdZggqZ3ZUMvXaKu6J8VzgwobKC3q1Lx8CYsHZeGEJU7d9DreHSPdTh0I.:16072::::::
    site123:$6$2.ZZMqBj$kFO1qi1UqGh4y3wcSDcEM5IoCMlljdZggqZ3ZUMvXaKu6J8VzgwobKC3q1Lx8CYsHZeGEJU7d9DreHSPdTh0I.:16072::::::
```

The to set the `$SITEID` edit the `.bashrc` file of the `site` user & add:

```
SITEID=$(who am i | awk '{print $1}')
```

- `ELSE`

The other approach you can take if using ssh key files is let everyone login as user `site`
but with their own keys, then in the `authorized_keys` file add the following to the start
of each different key line:

```
environment="SITEID=site123" ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC
environment="SITEID=site111" ssh-rsa AAAAJ2Oqka
```

that way they will still all have different site id's